# Can books give stat points or unlock skill points?

Tags: divinity-2-ego-draconis

In Divinity 2 : Ego Draconis, I have found 1 book so far that is explicitly named "Stat Book" and gave me one stat point to spend after reading.

But since you can also get Books as optional Quest rewards I ask myself what purpose they have. Are they just for lore fanatics or can you gain additional stats or skills by reading lore related books?

[image: Example for a book as quest reward]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Gamespot forums](http://www.gamespot.com/divinity-ii-ego-draconis/forum/books-in-divinity-ii-52467331/):

> most of them are useless. the important ones get stored automatically in the food/drink tab or the quest tab.

[Here](http://www.larian.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=404215) is a comprehensive list of Skill, Stat and Dragon Skill Books that can be found in the game.